# what does the power management applet do on a desktop?

Tags: power-management, services, startup-applications

ok, I understand what the power management daemon does on a laptop, conserving battery power by scaling down the cpu, and dimming the screen. On a desktop however, is the power management daemon necessary? (as in, is there anything else I am not thinking of, before I turn this off?)

Comment: Might be useful if you want the screen off after certain time, or the PC to autosuspend. It also has settings on what happens when the power button is pressed. What is does not do, is scale the CPU.